# Activity life cycle issues

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to hide a button in one of my activities if a global data structure does not exist (it's static, in  `public class Globals extends Application`).  Since I want to redraw the button whenever I resume the activity, but would rather not redraw the rest of the view, I put the initialization of the view in `onCreate()` and the button-hiding code in `onResume()`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myActivity);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if (Globals.datastructure == null) {
        ((Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton)).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

When I allocate the data structure and then go back to the activity from a different activity, `onResume` is executed correctly but the button does not reappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activity containing the button is probably not being recreated, which means that when you return to it from some other activity, the button is never being set (back) to be visible. You should probably change the `onResume()` to something like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    findViewById(R.id.myButton).setVisibility(Globals.datastructure == null ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
}
```

So basically you just have to make sure that whenever `Globals.datastructure != null`, you also change the visibility appropriately. In other words: an `else` is required with the `if`.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thanks!  If I redrew the view in `onResume()`, I would only have to worry about removing the button, but since I only draw the view when the activity is created, I also have to worry about adding it back in.